# SVG rendering not proper in IE browser

Tags: internet-explorer, mathjax

I am trying to Render SVG for the mathml.
 It looks fine on chrome, but in IE svg has additonal attributs to its tag How can we avoid these additional attributes being added?
 Please try to render below mathml as SVG in chrome and IE.
 You can see the difference in SVG tag which got generated (Attached scrrenshots in both browsers)

MathML is:

```
<math xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1998/Math/MathML"><mrow><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503163">1</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503164">2</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503165">3</mn><mtable columnalign="right" align="baseline 2" rowspacing="0.0ex" ID="63201617503166"><mtr><mtd><mrow><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503167">1</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503168">2</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503169">3</mn></mrow></mtd></mtr><mtr><mtd><menclose notation="longdiv"><mrow><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503170">1</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503171">2</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503172">3</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503173">4</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503174">5</mn></mrow></menclose></mtd></mtr><mtr><mtd><munder><mrow><mn style="font-family: inher[enter image description here][2]it;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503175">1</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503176">2</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503177">3</mn></mrow><mrow><mo>_</mo></mrow></munder><mphantom><mrow><mn>45</mn></mrow></mphantom></mtd></mtr><mtr><mtd><mrow><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503178">1</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503179">2</mn><mn style="font-family: inherit;font-style: inherit;" ID="63201617503180">3</mn></mrow></mtd></mtr></mtable></mrow></math>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: You should add a live demo.

Answer (score 1):

Note that those attributes are also in the first graphic, but they are farther to the right (note the `style="width: 10.751ex; height: 12.291ex...` that is at the right of the line containing the `<svg>` element.)  The output for IE should be exactly the same (modulo order of the attributes) as for all other browsers, as the SVG output does include have any browser-specific code.

The styles are important for getting the placement correct.  If the placement isn't correct for you, there may be other CSS on the page that is interfering.  You might try modifying your page so that it doesn't load any CSS and see if the SVG output is correct or not.  If it is, then add your CSS files in one at a time until you find the one that is the trouble.  Then look through that to see what might be at fault.

Otherwise, as Peter suggested, provide a live sample for us to look at.  Also, you imply that the IE output is not visually correct, but don't say in what way (saying the attributes differ is not the same as saying what the result looks like on screen, or providing a screen shot, for example).